# Input for a sprite in libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I am new in libGDX and making a simple game like bomber-man.I want to move a sprite in accordance with my touch. for example , if i touch below the image it have to move downside,if i touch in right side of image or sprite it should move in right direction. this should be happened continuously i.e when i touch screen any where,sprite should move continuously and when i release the touch,it should stop there.

Thanks in advance..

here is my code

```
    package com.kamal.bomberman;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector.GestureListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.RETURN;

public class Bomberman implements ApplicationListener  {
    private SpriteBatch batch;

    private Texture textureBg,textureBman;
    private TextureRegion regionBg , regionBman;
    float x = 5 , y = 630 ;


    @Override
    public void create() {      
         textureBg = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/bg.png"));
         textureBman = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/bm.png"));
         regionBman = new TextureRegion(textureBman,0,0,256,512);
         regionBg = new TextureRegion(textureBg,6,5,256,192);
         batch = new SpriteBatch();


    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {  
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(regionBg,0,0,800,1280);
        batch.draw(textureBman,x,y,300,300);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }




}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears that you want someone to program this for you

Comment: Just tell me the concept

Comment: Instead of posting open ended questions on SO, you should be looking at examples that come with libgdx first. See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/examples/MoveSpriteExample.java
From your question, it sounds like you barely scratched the surface of your problem before asking for help.